# Bind to LDAP with spring

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I apologize for the English, if there are errors. I need to add authorization via LDAP to my spring program, but an error occurs when trying to authorize the client:

`Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0907E9, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580]; remaining name 'uid=ben,ou=Пользователи'`

As I understand it, this is a program authorization error on the server. The credentials of an account with the rights to search in AD using the LDAP protocol are set via application.properties:

```
spring.ldap.username=
spring.ldap.password=
```

The code snippet responsible for authorization is identical to the code in the guide:

```
  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .ldapAuthentication()
        .userDnPatterns("(uid={0}),ou=Пользователи")
        .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
        .contextSource()
          .url("xxx")
          .and()
        .passwordCompare()
          .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
          .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
  }
```

I don't fully understand Spring, please tell me if there is an error. Could this error be related to the password encoding(in passwordEncoder() method)?

UPD.: the server uses 389-Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the solution, you need to specify the system account data when configuring requests:

```
auth
  .ldapAuthentication()
    .userSearchBase("ou=Пользователи")
    .userSearchFilter("sAMAccountName={0}")
      .contextSource()
        .url(sourceUrl)
        .managerDn(managerLogin)        // <--- this 
        .managerPassword(managerPassw); // <--- this
```